# Nhibernate ICriteria - Check property value length

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying to return all entities where a given property is not empty.
The problem is `IsNotEmpty()` only applies to collections. Below is the general approach I've taken so far, it obviously doesn't work.

```
ICriteria lvCriteria = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession()
                                       .CreateCriteria(typeof(FunctionCall))
                                       .SetMaxResults(100)
                                       .AddOrder(Order.Desc("LogId"));

if (pvMsg.HasValue)
{                
       lvCriteria.Add(Restrictions.IsNotNull("Msg"))
                 .Add(Restrictions.IsNotEmpty("Msg"));
}
```

Any suggestions?  Is it possible to achieve this result by checking the property value's length?  Thank you!

Comment: I either don't understand your code or don't understand what is obvious about what is not working.  Can you maybe provide some sample input data and some sample (expected vs. actual) output?

Comment: Msg is simply a text field which can be either empty, null, or contain some value.  I would like to return only those entities "FunctionCall" whose Msg property contains some value.  IsNotEmpty() only applies to collections, not single entities. (i.e. it returns true if a list contains items, but throws an exception if used on a single property).

Given 3 FunctionCall entities with 3 separate values "   ", null, and "ERROR" for the property Msg, I would expect only one entity returned from my query, the one which contains "ERROR".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I discovered the combination I was looking for!

```
lvCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Not(Expression.Eq("Msg", string.Empty)));
```

This combination of Restrictions and Expression works as expected; narrowing out all empty strings.  I do not know why I could not achieve these results earlier even with:

```
lvCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("Msg", string.Empty)));
```

Thank you to all who tried.

Comment: Perfect. I am new to NHibernate and was wondering why I couldn't do `.IsNotEmpty` as expected and now I know (and I know what to do instead). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for:

```
.Add(Expression.IsNotEmpty("PropertyName"));
```

and

```
.Add(Expression.IsNotNull("PropertyName"));
```

Comment: In fact that is not what I'm looking for.  IsNotEmpty() applies only to collections (i.e. bags, sets, etc.)!  If I am wrong, please let me know.  I would like to check the value of "Msg" for each individual entity and return only those who have a value.  The equivalent of        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pvMsg)) { ... }

Comment: Expression.IsNotEmpty() is the same as !string.IsNullOrEmpty().

Comment: Notice that I'm using the EXPRESSION class, not the RESTRICTIONS class (as you did in the post)

Comment: Yes I did notice the difference - I had before and have since tried Expression in place of Restrictions..these both result in the following MappingException:

Property path [Assembly.Domain.FunctionCall.Msg] does not reference a collection

Thank you.

Comment: can you post the mappings & class definition?  this works on my machine but maybe there's something i'm missing

Answer (score 0):

Below are my mapping and class definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" assembly="Domain" namespace="Assembly.Domain">
  <class name="Assembly.Domain.FunctionCall, Domain" lazy="false" table="FunctionCallLog">

    <id name="LogId" column="LogId">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="LogTime" column="LogTime" />
    <property name="Username" column="Username" />
    <property name="CallerIp" column="CallerIp" />
    <property name="FunctionName" column="FunctionName" />
    <property name="Parameters" column="Parameters" />
    <property name="Msg" column="Msg" />
    <property name="FileName" column="FileName" />
    <property name="TimeSpan" column="TimeSpan" />

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


using System;

namespace Assembly.Domain
{
    public class FunctionCall
    {
        public int LogId { get; set; }
        public DateTime LogTime { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string CallerIp { get; set; }
        public string FunctionName { get; set; }
        public string Parameters { get; set; }
        public string Msg { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public int TimeSpan { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ICriteria lvCriteria = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession()
                                       .CreateCriteria(typeof(FunctionCall))
                                       .SetMaxResults(100)
                                       .AddOrder(Order.Desc("LogId"));

if (pvMsg.HasValue)
{                
       lvCriteria.Add(Restrictions.IsNotNull("Msg"))
                 .Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("Msg", ""));
}
```

There may be a more compact way of expressing this.

Comment: I've tried that as well, it does not work as expected.
I guess I should make clear that perhaps IsNotEmpty() does not work because I need to apply this filter as the collection is being populated; this is to avoid a timeout as this table contains 1,000,000+ records.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to apply this filter as the collection is being populated"? If the query is timing out then you should grab the SQL issued by NH execute it directly and inspect the query execution plan.

Comment: It times out due to the amount of data coming back; it uses ungodly amounts of server memory.  Is it not possible to say 'only grab entities whose Msg property contains a value' rather than 'grab all Msgs then return only those whose Msg property have a value'?

I.E. only picking the good apples off the tree rather than picking all the apples and then throwing out the bad ones?

Comment: The Criteria API generates a SQL statement that is executed on the database server. There is no client side filtering done. I strongly suggest you profile your application to see the SQL statements are being issued.